# Mass action delete not working on Magento 2.1.9

Tags: magento2, controllers, delete, massaction

I have created a backend module on magento **2.1.6** which was working fine on the mass delete action.

After upgrading magento with version **2.1.9**, now if i tried to make a mass delete i receive this next err :

```
Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method namespace\module\Model\ResourceModel\Post\Grid\Collection::_getAllIdsSelect();
```

on this function:

```
  public function getAllIds($limit = null, $offset = null)
    {
        return $this->getConnection()->fetchCol($this->_getAllIdsSelect($limit, $offset), $this->_bindParams);
    }
```

Does anyone know how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

you can add this function to your namespace\module\Model\ResourceModel\Post\Grid\Collection.php :

```
protected function _getAllIdsSelect($limit = null, $offset = null)
{
    $idsSelect = clone $this->getSelect();
    $idsSelect->reset(\Magento\Framework\DB\Select::ORDER);
    $idsSelect->reset(\Magento\Framework\DB\Select::LIMIT_COUNT);
    $idsSelect->reset(\Magento\Framework\DB\Select::LIMIT_OFFSET);
    $idsSelect->reset(\Magento\Framework\DB\Select::COLUMNS);
    $idsSelect->columns($this->getResource()->getIdFieldName(), 'main_table');
    $idsSelect->limit($limit, $offset);
    return $idsSelect;
}
```

hopefully useful for you.